# Настройка Nginx, proxy_pass на поддомен

Tags: nginx

Имеется основное веб-приложение, расположенное на неком домене example.ru, и Json API, расположенное на поддомене api.example.ru. Запрос к api.example.ru/sitemap динамически генерирует xml файл карты сайта. Необходимо, чтобы запрос к example.ru/sitemap.xml переадресовывался к данной точке доступа API. Не очень опытен в настройке Nginx, поэтому с этим возникли сложности. Текущий конфиг (лишнее опустил):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.ru;

    root /home/web/example.ru/www/dist;
    index index.html;

    location = /sitemap.xml {
        proxy_pass "http://api.example.ru/sitemap";
    }

    location ~ \. {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 1m;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.ru;

    root /home/web/example.ru/www/api/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \. {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /index.php =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
    }
}
```

При таком конфиге сервер перенаправляет запрос example.ru/sitemap.xml к веб-приложению, потому отображается страница 404 ошибки веб-приложения.
Сервер изначально выбирает правильный location (проверил методом замены содержимого блока location = /sitemap.xml на return 200 'Test';), но при проксировании запрос приходит к тому же самому блоку server, а не ко второму, соответствующему поддомену api.*. Приходит он теперь с $uri = /sitemap, поэтому закономерно выбирается location / и отображается веб-приложение.
DNS настроен верно, и веб-приложение и API доступны по тем доменам, по каким и задумано, локальный запрос curl'ом к api.example.ru/sitemap корректно возвращает карту сайта. В общем, я очевидно что-то недопонимаю в конфигурации Nginx. Был бы признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю проблему, вам нужно указать в локейшене с проксипасом заголовок Host:

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    proxy_set_header Host api.example.ru;
    proxy_pass "http://api.example.ru/sitemap";
}
```

В вашем варианте конфига вы указали адрес проксируемого сервера, он зарезолвился, но хост при этом остался от первоначального запроса, поэтому вы снова попали к тому же блоку server.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Стоило догадаться, что Nginx именно по заголовку Host определяет сервер. Что-то затупил.